# Android and libCurl https

Tags: android, android-ndk, libcurl

Good evening,

I need to implement libCurl into one of our Android projects. I use JNI to call the c++ class with the libCurl code. Everything works just perfect but for the love of god I can't get it to work using a https url. 
I always get the CURLE_UNSUPPORTED_PROTOCOL error.

I'm using 
[this prebuild curl library](https://github.com/minggo/libcurl-build/tree/master/prebuild-with-ssl) with SSL

My c++ code looks like this:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.es....");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void *)&chunk);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 0);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PROGRESSDATA, (void *)&cbProgress);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, progress_func);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);

status = curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

I use the same code for iOS and it works fine with https. 
Again, using a http url works just fine.

Any help is truly appreciated !!

Answer (score 1):

From [libcurl errors manpage](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/libcurl-errors/):

```
   CURLE_UNSUPPORTED_PROTOCOL (1)
          The URL you passed to libcurl used a protocol that this  libcurl
          does  not  support.  The  support might be a compile-time option
          that you didn't use, it can be a misspelled protocol  string  or
          just a protocol libcurl has no code for.
```

The `compile-time option` is the important takeaway of this. So, test the library that you're using with `curl_version_info()` (manpage [here](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_version_info.html)) to see if it contains `SSL` support or not. The library doc may say it has `SSL` support, but please confirm. If it doesn't contain `SSL` support, then no `https`.

Comment: Thanks Samveen. I checked the SSL Version and it returns (null). Dang! Do you have any other resources where i can download a precompiled libcurl library with SSL support?

Comment: Why not build it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

You need compile libcurl.so with "--with-ssl"

Which is really suffering. Refer "http://ieroot.com/2015/03/29/1728.html", may help you .